# iPad PDF reader app with seamless handwritting annotation experience

Tags: ipad, applications, software-recommendation, pdf, handwriting

I am looking for an iPad app (Android app references will also be considered useful) which allows reading PDF files and annotating them with a stylus, resembling the experience I would have with a pen and a piece of paper as closely as possible.

This requires:

1. Not enforcing to go through button clicking, context menus or popups
   every time I want to write something. (i.e. add annotation, accept
   annotation). It completely breaks the reading experience.

   I don't even care if that kind of a step-based work-flow is better if you want to edit/delete the annotations. I would be happy even if deletion/edition was not allowed, a good old cross-out would be enough for me.
2. The writing experience should be snappy and responsive. I don't want lines to follow my stylus-tip as I write, like laggy comets in orbit. A good example of good behaviour in this regard is Wacom's *Bamboo Write* App

Optionally it would be simply awesome if it was had handwritting calculator capabilities like MyScript Calculator. I am used to make calculations in the margins, when reading engineering or math-related books.

I have tried [Goodreader](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-ipad/id363448914?mt=8) and [iAnnotate](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/iannotate-pdf/id363998953?mt=8) but neither of them comply with (1) or (2). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! [Good notes](http://www.goodnotesapp.com/) does exactly (1) and (2)

You can write without accessing menus and browse the document at the same time by using two-finger gestures (to distinguish them from the writing itself). And writing is really snappy.

It also happens to have a great feedback system, so I added a suggestion to add a handwritting calculator.

The only missing features (for my taste) are [margin cropping](http://www.goodreader.net/gr-man-view-pdf.html#crop) and automatic Dropbox synching.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Adobe Reader by Adobe](https://itunes.apple.com/app/adobe-reader/id469337564?mt=8) There is a version for Andriod too, and it is free as well.

Comment: No you can't, specially not (1). You need to click buttons in order to annotate and then save the annotations. Please read questions carefully before answering.

Comment: My bad. Sorry I am not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I use my iPad all the time at work and during meeting, it's important to import, make annotation and share my files with people. To do this I use Beesy, really nice app, I can read my pdf files on iPad easier, it's very good tool for profesional: http://www.beesapps.com/management-productivity/import-and-read-pdf-files-on-ipad/
I saw they are on Trunk Evernote so I think it's can be interesting.

Sofye.

Comment: I don't think it complies with (1).

Comment: I watched the demo, I couldn't see any annotation of PDF.